# Apache Mina Java FTP Server Implementation - Client Stuck Waiting For Welcome Message

Tags: java, ftp, mina

I am implementing an FTP server in Java for a project.  I can start the server but when I try to connect with a client it is stuck on "waiting for welcome message".  I've looked at several examples but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  Here is the class I have.  I will eventually break some of this out into other methods.

The user parameters have been cleared for the purposes of this post.

```
public class FTPServer {


final int PORT = 2221;
String userfile = "";
String username="";
String password = ""
String homedir ="";

private FtpServer server=null;
public FTPServer() {}

public FTPServer(final String ipaddress, final int port){   


FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
ListenerFactory listenerfactory = new ListenerFactory();

    listenerfactory.setDataConnectionConfiguration(
    new DataConnectionConfigurationFactory().createDataConnectionConfiguration());

    ConnectionConfigFactory connection = new ConnectionConfigFactory();
    connection.setMaxLoginFailures(10);
    connection.setLoginFailureDelay(5);
    connection.setAnonymousLoginEnabled(false);

// set the ip address of the listener
listenerfactory.setServerAddress(ipaddress);

// set the port of the listener
if (port == 0)
{ listenerfactory.setPort(PORT);}

else {listenerfactory.setPort(port);
// replace the default listener
serverFactory.addListener("default", listenerfactory.createListener());
     serverFactory.setConnectionConfig(connection.createConnectionConfig());

}

PropertiesUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
userManagerFactory.setFile(new File(userfile));
userManagerFactory.setPasswordEncryptor(new SaltedPasswordEncryptor());
UserManager um = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();
BaseUser user = new BaseUser();

user.setName(username);
user.setPassword(password);
user.setHomeDirectory(homedir);
try {
    um.save(user);
} catch (FtpException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    this.StopServer();
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

serverFactory.setUserManager(um);
    server = serverFactory.createServer();

}

public void  StopServer(){ this.server.stop(); }

public void StartServer()
{
try {
    server.start();
} catch (FtpException e) {
    // handle this eventually, good enough for testing now
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Here is the code that creates the server and starts and stops it

```
final int port = 0;
final String ipaddress = "";
FTPServer server = new FTPServer(ipaddress,port);
server.StartServer();
 server.StopServer();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that `FtpServer.Start` only starts listening on the incoming port. It does not block. You kill the server immediately afterwards by calling `.Stop`.

You have to wait in your code explicitly to keep the server running.

```
server.StartServer();
Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: Do I still need the sleep if I have a breakpoint set at StartServer()?  I run to the breakpoint and start the server, then try the connection. 
 Eventually there will be file transfers happening between StartServer() and StopServer()

Comment: If your server is paused in debugger, it can hardly accept connections.

Comment: hmmm  what I meant was I set a break point at StopServer(), and in the debugger I can see that the server is running.  at least the property that says whether it's running is set to true.

Comment: That's what I mean. You have stopped the process in the debugger (I mean whole process here, not the FTP server). So it cannot accept requests. And once you resume the process, it calls `StopServer`. So there's no moment, when it can accept incoming requests. Did you even tried to use the `sleep` as I've suggested?

Comment: Not yet.  I will try that.  I misunderstood what the breakpoint does and was just trying to understand that.  thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I tried adding the Thread.Sleep().  I had the same problem and after it resumed from sleep it threw in IncomatibleClassChange exception.  I'm going to look around and see if I can find some more sample code that implements the server.  I'm trying to embed a server in another larger project.